# Polymer, observe global var

Tags: javascript, variables, global, polymer, observers

I have a multiple custom elements that share the same list of data.
I'm trying to fire an event when the global list is changed.

The folowing code is working on FF and Safari, but not on Chrome.
Any suggestion for the issue, or maybe a better way to do it?

Thanks,

```
 (function() {
        var _list = null;

        Polymer("dmw-datatypes", {
            ready:function(){
                ...retreiving a list async...
            },
            get list() {
                return _list;
            },
            listReceived: function(json) {
                _list=json;
            },
            listChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
                this.fire('list-received');
            }
        });
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a symptom of the fact that `Object.observe()` (which is native in Chrome) [doesn't work out-of-the-box](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/#toc-synth-change-records) with computed properties (like your `get list() {}`). The other browsers use manual dirty-checking to polyfill this behavior, so they work fine. Basically, you're going to need to create your own Object.observe() notifier

```
var notifier = Object.getNotifier(this);
```

and notify observers when you update `_list` using `notifier.notify()`. The above link gives an example of this.